# NETBEANS 10 quando eu crio um projeto javaFX FXMLApplication

Tags: javafx, netbeans, java-11

Estou usando o DEBIAN 9

*https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx // entrei aqui e nada pois tem que fazer sempre

- Estou com NEtbeans 10 , quando eu crio um projeto javaFX FXMLApplication da o seguinte erro
- Já esta inslado o Javafx 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGKBm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaLoz.jpg

```
Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform Please go to Platform 
Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX 
tab,enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX 
Runtime.
tenho isntalado no Debian 9 java --version  
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

JAVAFX ativada também https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xZEB.jpg

Comment: solve here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKqu_3hPYn0 \0/

Comment: Tive que add outra #jdk =>  jdk-8u201-linux-x64